# Why there is a low frequency?

Tags: adc, sampling

I take the function \$ \sin(2 \cdot \pi \cdot f \cdot t) \$.

with \$ f = 1 \$

And plot it in excel with sampling frequency fd = 4,10

[image: sine values + plot]

Why there is a low frequency?

Comment: hm, which low frequency? This looks exactly like I'd expect!

Comment: Aliasing? Or wrong calculation. There is not shown exactly how you calculate it.

Comment: Your sampling rate is "Barely adequate" which here results in sampling "at the wrong moment". See figure 11 in this article which explains what's happening: https://www.wescottdesign.com/articles/Sampling/sampling.pdf

Comment: @MarkoBuršič the calculation looks correct, and I don't see any aliasing here.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie this is oversampling by a factor 2.05. Everything is right about that plot :) I wouldn't call it "barely" adequate, but figure 11 from your link illustrates the issue quite well.

Comment: I re-created this in Octave and I get a very similar plot. Make the sampling frequency 41 and you get a proper sinewave. @MarcusMüller Nyquist only said we can reconstruct a sine properly with oversampling = 1 or 2 or 4 (and adequate filtering) but not with 2.05. Nyquist is a bit sneaky in that respect.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You see that envelope, don't you? The OP asks why the result is not pure sine.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič but "envelope detection on samples" is not "a frequency that's in the signal"; speaking in "analog electronics" thinking, that is a highly non-linear operation that can introduce new signal components. I know why this confusion – see my answer. The thing that's wrong here is connecting the dots with straight lines :)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yep, as was to be expected :) see my answer; both octave and Excel do the same thing if you ask them to `plot`, and that's not correct for band-limited signals, see my answer :)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie no, Nyquist says *any* sampling rate > 2 B is sufficient. 2.05 most definitely is.

Comment: But that is assuming there is the a sinc function in place.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie no, that applies to any band-limited signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks right about your calculation, AND your plot! Nothing's wrong; there's no other frequency than \$f=1\$ in here.

What is confusing you is the fact that your excel plot *incorrectly* connects the sample points with straight lines. That isn't how reconstruction works!

You'd need to *sinc*-interpolation (with infinitely long sinc functions, that you shift to every sample position) to get the original sampled signal back.

Comment: Ok. But what if I feed these samples to ADC? I.m sure I will get a low frequncy component.

Comment: You mean a DAC. And: No, you won't. This signal is sufficiently sampled – full stop. the fact that you're "seeing" a low-frequency component is really just an artifact of your plot. The reconstruction filter after your DAC won't be trying to connect samples with straight lines.

Comment: Yes, DAC.
Reconstruction filter is a low pass filter. It will filter out high frequenies, but low frequencies will remain.

I made an example in Ocatve.

f=1;
fd=4.1;
dt = 1/fd;
t=1:dt:30;
y = sin (2*pi*f*t);

t1 = 1:dt/4:30;
y1=zeros(1,476);
y1(1:4:end) = y(1:end);
y1(2:4:end) = y(1:end);
y1(3:4:end) = y(1:end);
y1(4:4:end) = y(1:end);

y2 = zeros(1,476);
for k=1:length(y1)-1
    y2(k+1) = y2(k) + (y1(k)-y2(k))*0.5;
endfor


plot(t1,y1,"b")
hold on
plot(t1,y2,"r")
hold off

This simulates DAC output and filters it with RC filter. But the low frequency still remain

Comment: But there is **no** low frequency. Seriously. There's no low frequency coming out of your DAC.  I can't really help you believe that if you don't want to – but there's no low frequency. The fact that you're seeing "low frequency" is just your brain telling you how to interepret your graph. Your brain is wrong.

Comment: Will there be amplitude modulaton on DAC's output? Then there will be low frequency.

Comment: there won't be. I don't know how often I need to repeat that. Your RC reconstruction filter is incorrectly designed – try with one that cuts off significantly enough below  half your `fd`. Also, you're trying to simulate an analog reconstruction filter at the digital sampling rate you want to reconstruct – that can't work.

Comment: Tried that. Tried RC filter with Tau=0.5 to 0.00005 this is far below half of fd. There is still LF at output.
See this bucket in Octave online 
https://octave-online.net/bucket~SSL93c3m5EY8jWc4hrew9t

Comment: Hmm. Seems like I begin to understand. Plotted output samples are also connected with straight lines. This produces the effect of amplitude modulation

Answer (score 0):

The `sin` function in excel expects to receive as argument the angle in radians, so first you have to convert it. Try the following:

$$\sin(2\pi \cdot f \cdot t \cdot \frac{\pi}{180^°})$$

Comment: OP is already doing that.

Comment: Actually he is not. If you calculate e.g. \$sin(2\pi \cdot 1Hz \cdot 0.2439s)=0.0267\$ which is different than the one \$0.999\$ he ends up with.

Comment: the point I'm making is that angles in degree appear nowhere in his calculation; the existence of the unit "°" doesn't matter to the formulas at all.

Comment: I see your point. The problem seems indeed to be related with the interpolation curve produced by excel. (+1) for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the 'low frequency' the OP is talking about is the apparent amplitude modulation. I say 'apparent' because it's an artifact of the straight line interpolation.

If we take an approximation to the energy of the signal as the average energy of two adjacent samples, then it can be seen that two samples with amplitudes (1,0) or (0.7071,0.7071) will have the same mean energy. There is no amplitude modulation.

If you feed these samples into a DAC with no anti-alias filter after it, then the DAC will perform a hold 'interpolation'. That is, it will connect the points not with a straight line between them, but by holding the previous value until the next value comes in. If you look at the signal with an oscilloscope, then the display will have the same envelope as you see now, and you will think there is amplitude modulation.

The signal energy, as approximated by the total energy of two adjacent sample points, by the same argument as above, will be more or less constant. There is still no amplitude modulation.

If you follow the DAC with an anti-alias filter that passes DC to f>=1, and cuts off for f>3, and look at the filter output, then the waveform will 'magically' smooth into a constant amplitude sinewave, as the filter effectively performs higher order interpolation on the signal points.

Comment: But if i feed these samples to DAC I will get low frequency amplitude modulation on output.

Comment: No, you won't. There's no low frequency in the signal. It's an illusion, caused by the fact how you *draw* your graph. It's not there in the signal.

Comment: @XeenychXeenych it depends what you mean by 'get', see my expanded answer.